# Why can I pass a subarray into `Array#each`?

Tags: ruby, each

I understand that `each` passes each element of an array to the block. In the following, each element of the array should be `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`, not `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

```
arr = [[1,2], [3,4]]
arr.each {|item1, item2| puts " #{item1} #{item2} "}
#  1 2
#  3 4
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Why does the following work?

```
arr.each {|item| puts item}
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# => [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

Comment: It's a Ruby feature called Destructuring.

Comment: Also you need to understand how puts works with an Array. puts when passed an array will print each item on it's own line that's why it outputs like that. It only iterates twice but looks like it iterates 4 times due to the puts output.

Comment: Try replacing `puts item` with `p item`.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the elements that are passed to the block by `each` are `[1, 2]`, `[3, 4]`, ... and not `1`, `2`, ... When the number of parameters do not match in (block) variable assignment, an array is destructed in an attempt to make them match. In your case, you have an equivalent of:

```
item1, item2 = [1, 2]
```

and the right side has less parameters than the left side. So the array on the right is destructed as:

```
item1, item2 = 1, 2
```

You can explicitly write this as:

```
{|(item1, item2)| ...}
```

but parentheses here can be omitted:

```
{|item1, item2| ...}
```

Comment: The feature explained here is called parallel assignment in Ruby.

Comment: Not really. This isn't assignment, it's parameter binding. However, in older versions of Ruby, parameter binding of blocks used assignment semantics. It no longer does, but some features were kept for convenience and backwards compatibility, including array destructuring. Imagine having to use `Hash#each` without destructuring.